# Send file via intent action_send to another device with result code and use it

Tags: android, android-intent, return-code

I'm using this code to send a file to another device:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send File"));
```

This works very well, but I need to get a result code, if the file is received on the other device.

Also I want to use the received file in the same application on the other device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Activity.onActivityResult() then check it's parameters:

**requestCode:** identifies which app returned these results. You wil define this when you call startActivityForResult().

**resultCode:** informs you whether this app succeeded, failed, or something different.

**data:** holds any information returned by this app. This may be null.

Also check [this tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/) for code sample.